# How to make two same inner classes in a instance mapping in Mybatis (Java)

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis

I'm using class `Hand` to save datas. It inclues two same inner class `Card`, which means two `Card`s make up one `Hand`. As the following:

```
public class Card {
    private Integer id;
    private Integer number;
    private Integer color;

    public Card() {}
    public Card(int number, int color) {
        this.number = number;
        this.color = color;
    }
```

```
public class Hand {

    private Integer id;

    private Card card1,card2;

    public Hand() {}
    public Hand(Card a, Card b) {
        card1 = a;
        card2 = b;
    }
}
```

Then I make the mapping xml like this:

```
    <resultMap id="handMap" type="com.company.handsmap.Hand">
        <id column="id" property="id"/>
        <association property="card1" resultMap="cardMap"/>
        <association property="card2" resultMap="cardMap"/>
    </resultMap>

    <resultMap id="cardMap" type="com.company.handsmap.Card">
        <id column="id" property="id"/>
        <result column="number" property="number"/>
        <result column="color" property="color"/>
    </resultMap>

    <select id="getAllHand" resultMap="handMap">
        SELECT
        *
        FROM Hand H
        LEFT JOIN Card c1 ON H.card1_id = c1.id
        LEFT JOIN Card c2 ON H.card2_id = c2.id
    </select>
```

Then I used mapping as the following and it seems get something wrong:
[Debugging the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sEop.png)

As the it shows that the `Hand` got the correct `Card`1 but got `null` in `Card`2

If I run

```
SELECT
        *
        FROM Hand H
        LEFT JOIN Card c1 ON H.card1_id = c1.id
        LEFT JOIN Card c2 ON H.card2_id = c2.id
```

in database, I can get right result as the following:
[SQL results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgeGm.png)

Can someone tell me where is the problem and how can I fix it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I change the mapper.xml like the following and it comes the correct result

```
    <resultMap id="cardMap1" type="com.company.handsmap.Card">
        <id column="id" property="id"/>
        <result column="c1number" property="number"/>
        <result column="c1color" property="color"/>
    </resultMap>

    <!--Create another Map for Card2-->
    <resultMap id="cardMap2" type="com.company.handsmap.Card">
        <id column="id" property="id"/>
        <result column="c2number" property="number"/>
        <result column="c2color" property="color"/>
    </resultMap>

    <select id="getAllHand" resultMap="handMap">
        SELECT
        H.*,
        c1.id as c1id, c1.number as c1number, c1.color as c1color,
        c2.id as c2id, c2.number as c2number, c2.color as c2color
        FROM Hand H
        LEFT JOIN Card c1 ON H.card1_id = c1.id
        LEFT JOIN Card c2 ON H.card2_id = c2.id
    </select>
```

It needs two cardMap and make sure they can both get the data from the database column correctly

Comment: You just need one result map for `Card` if you use `columnPrefix`. See the [doc](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#nested-results-for-association).